# I am unable to access docShell for my browser element in xul?

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-addon, xul

```
<browser id="search" type="content-targetable" src="www.google.com">
</browser>
```

Javascript Code

```
// I am using script to set the property of browser element

var x=document.getElementById('search');

x.docshell.allowAuth="false"     // The code stops here

x.docshell.allowPlugin="false"   //This does not work
```

Comment: When are you running that code?

Comment: I call the script using a function after creating the browser element.... However the script does not work at that point.....
I think that some mozilla service is required for this function to work......

Comment: [link] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIDocShell)
This link is helpful....But I can not find the way to run this script

Comment: Btw, Firefox has an [Error Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Error_Console) - you should look up the error rather than saying "the code stops here".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with many XUL tags, the `<browser>` tag isn't inherently "special" - the "special" functionality is added by [XBL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XBL). The important thing is that XBL bindings are added via CSS rules and for these CSS rules to apply the element has to be inserted into the document. So it is important to insert the element first and only access the special properties after that. Of course, in this case some asynchronous initialization might be required as well so you better do something like:

```js
var browser = document.createElement(browser);
parent.appendChild(browser);
window.setTimeout(initBrowser, 0);

function initBrowser()
{
  x.docShell.allowAuth = false;
  ...
  browser.loadURI("...", null, null);
}
```

Note that it's `docShell` (your example used wrong captalization) and that `allowAuth` is a boolean, not a string.